# XSD for one XML element name but different attributes in same parent element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Here is the XML:

```
<lists>
   <list refname="list_refname"/>
   <list refname="list_refname_template_1" use_for="template_1"/>
   <list refname="list_refname_template_2" use_for="template_2"/>
   <list refname="list_refname_template_3" use_for="template_3"/>
</lists>
```

And the XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="lists">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="refname" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="refname" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                  <xsd:attribute name="use_for" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The idea is:

- list element only with attribute `refname` must appears only once
- list elements with attributes `refname` and `use_for might` appear any
  times or none

Does it possible within XSD?

If yes, how to re-write my not-working XSD?

Answer (score 0):

XSD has an [**Element Declarations Consistent**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-element-consistent)  constraint that requires that same named elements within a content model have consistent content models.  Your `list` element violates this constraint by having two different content models within `lists` content model.

Resolution can take one of the following forms:

1. Rename one of the `list` elements.
2. Remove the sibling relationship between the two inconsistent `list` content models.
3. Use the most general declaration of the `list` element. If using XSD 1.0, forgo the additional constraints on the attributes; if using XSD 1.1, use `xs:assert` to specify the addition constraints on the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!